# Is there any logs I can enable for spring-data-jpa to see why it is slow in Tomcat?

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a query which runs in about 6ms in DBeaver and I used the general log to extract the query that is being passed in which is the same database that my Tomcat server is connected to

```
select min(organizati0_.Downloaded) as col_0_0_ from oss_collection_history organizati0_ 
where organizati0_.AccountingSystem='SomeSystem' 
and (organizati0_.Org in ('ID1' , 'ID2', ..., 'ID10' ))
```

On a JUnit test running Spring Data JPA against a Dockerized copy of the database, the query also runs quite fast 60ms, but on Tomcat it takes upwards of 8-10 seconds.

So not exactly sure what's going on.

I just do this to profile the function call using the same parameters.

```
var start = System.currentTimeMillis();
consolidatedDownloadSvc.getAvailableYearsOfDownloadedForAccountingSystem(...);
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
```

It does not appear on slowlog even if I `set global log_queries_not_using_indexes = 'ON';` so that would indicate to me that the query is indexed.

So I was wondering if there's some sort of log that will show me any extra things I may be missing in Spring-Data and Hibernate.

Comment: Are you comparing performance against a local DB running in Docker vs. a remote DB or what's the slower environment exactly?

Comment: In Tomcat it's significantly slower compared to JUnit.  I don't mind if it is a factor of 10 compared to JUnit in Docker, because factor of 10 is still under a second.  i.e. 600ms.  
6 ms for MySQL client over JDBC, 60ms in a test container docker and 8000ms with Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from what @Panagiotis suggested it will also be helpful to enable below stats to understand in what phase is hibernate spending more time.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=DEBUG
```

You would see something like below in your logs

```
2021-12-29 10:54:52.408  INFO 31972 - – [           main] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
    5070899 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    4359903 nanoseconds spent preparing 20 JDBC statements;
    76117198 nanoseconds spent executing 20 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    132026893 nanoseconds spent performing 40 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    838900 nanoseconds spent performing 19 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    16900 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

Comment: This probably would've been useful a few minutes ago. :)
I'll check it out, but after trying out a few things it appears that there's some "lingering information" when running in tomcat.

Namely the access control which used hibernate caused some data to be left in memory (since I know I don't plan to use it I just did an entityManager.clear and it made things run MUCH faster)